# How to use only visible/filtered rows of excel in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel - which sometimes needs to be manually opened - filtered - saved - and closed.

But Pandas is not using the filtered xlsx- it uses the entire excel sheet. Went through few answers here and the solution given is using openpyxl Python library. But my code is huge and uses Pandas library mainly and it is working fine. Is there a way using Pandas to use visible/filtered data of xlsx?

Below is a part of working code. Is there any keywords in Pandas which can be incorporated anywhere below to use just the visible/filtered excel? Any help is much appreciated.

```
def json_file(i_fname, indexList, i_code, i_path):
    PathLink = os.path.join(i_path, i_fname + '.json') #Path Name Formation Eg.C:/..xyz.json      
    excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('input.xlsx',
                                          sheet_name='input_sheet1',
                                          usecols=indexList, #index starts from 0                                          
                                          dtype={'codenum': str,
                                                  'name': str,
                                                  'school': str,
                                                  'city': str})  # datatype 
    df_filtered = excel_data_df.loc[excel_data_df["codenum"]==i_code]    # Row Filtering
    df_filtered.columns = ['Code', 'Student Name', 'Class', 'School Name','City Name'] #renaming 
    cols_to_keep = ['Student Name', 'Class', 'School Name','City Name'] # columns to keep 
    df_filtered = df_filtered[cols_to_keep]  # columns to keep
    df_filtered                                # columns to keep
    json_str = df_filtered.to_json(PathLink,orient='records',indent=2) #json converted file
```

Comment: I would add a macro in the excel which will copy only the filtered rows from your sheet to a new tab and read just that tab using pandas.

Comment: @Divya any luck on the solution to this? except for using openpyxl and reading row by row.